# Folder selection in MVC web application c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, web-applications, folderbrowserdialog

I am working on one MVC web application project, which require one field called folder selection just like `FolderBrowserDialog` in windows application.

Help me to find that `FolderBrowserDialog` for web application. Is there any solution for folder selection in MVC??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. You can use a  to select a file, but modern browsers will not send a path for security reasons (and your browser does not have access to paths on the server)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such control (except using ActiveX Control or Java Applets), so don't waste your time to look for it and you can not get any folder path(on the client machine) with JavaScript due to security reasons.

Why don't you just allow the user to download the file and user will select the folder where he wants that file to be saved or else it will get saved in default folder of the browser.

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I want to save system generated PDF files on that presaved folder path. Means user will define that path in system configuration, later when application will generate PDFs, it should be saved on that saved folder path. Any solution for that??

Comment: My method is to create user folder when user is created and save any document for that user in that folder. So a folder is automatic associate to a user.